# “Instance reachability check failed” when launching an AWS EC2 instance from a custom AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I got this issue

couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (240)
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(8,1)

can anyone please help to resolve this issue

Comment: Sounds like it could be an [issue](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=597751) with settings related to virtualization type.  Did you make the custom AMI yourself?  Is it PV or HVM?  What class of instance is involved?  More info is needed... and I think this is going to be a question that belongs on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).